# About Holdem Manager graphs

Tags: texas-hold-em

When I go to Opponents tab -> Summaries in down right corner I have Group Profile and have option to choose to look different states bar graphs, for example for VP$IP I have these:

http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/6773/captureucr.jpg

What does player count (X cordinate) represent (number of players at the table?) and what does these 0-2.5% 2.5-5% 5-7.5%... and bar graphs represent. Can somoone explain this picture for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell this gives you a distribution of players for a given stat. In your example it is VP$IP. You have played against 0 players which have a VPIP of 0 - 2.5%, 0 players with a VPIP of 2.5 - 5%, 1 player with a VPIP of 5 - 7.5% etc. THe highlighted column shows you where the player you have selected is in. So the on you are looking at (which username you have erased) is in the range of 20 - 22.5% VPIP

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

It's known as a **Histogram** and looks at frequencies of observations occurring in certain ranges of values.

More details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).